# What kind of OpenSource solution to do video streaming?

Tags: video, music, open-source, streaming, theora

I am looking for a solution to do streaming of 5 videos streams (with audio) on the Internet.

What kind of OpenSource can I use ?
I heard about Red5 but we need Flash Player.
Is it yet possible do to that with HTML5 video tag ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use VLC for video streaming.

I think the [HTML5 video tag](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726002026/http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html) can be directly used to embed video files and there shouldn't even be the need for a streaming server.

Answer (score 0):

To stream flash try [flvstreamer](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/flvstreamer/). It needs some setup and thinkering though.